# Homegenize tags? "microsoft-excel", "powerpoint"

Tags: discussion, tags

We have tags [microsoft-excel](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) and [powerpoint](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint).

Is there a reason for this discrepancy?

What should we do?

Comment: Before it falls asleep: Was the consense now to use the `microsoft-` prefix on all of them, and should we rename the tags accordingly?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you want a software that excels (as every 3rd question asks for "the best"). But as that would be a meta-tag then, you're correct it shouldn't be ambiguous.

But then think to say a word: seeing that as tag might make you think twice before recognizing it as MSWord (and not e.g. word-processing in general) – or seeing `access` you might be asking "what does the OP want to access?" before recognizing it as [microsoft-access](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access). We should also think about keeping tags in "the same style"; so if you now rename this one to `excel`, the next question will regard [microsoft-word](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) or [microsoft-access](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access) – and then?

Most other MS tags have the leading `microsoft-` (see: [microsoft-onenote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-onenote), [microsoft-exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-exchange), [microsoft-access](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access)), so I'd rather say [powerpoint](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint) should adjust to that and be renamed to [microsoft-powerpoint](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint).

Comment: This is in line with how [SU] does it http://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-access/info, http://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-excel/info, http://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-powerpoint/info

Comment: @JanDoggen It's also in-line with how we do it on Android.SE: though it's clear that the Galaxy devices are made by Samsung, the tags are `samsung-galaxy-*` :) But yes, you've named the exact correspondence. So if all other sites use that for *this* tag, we should stick to that.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest renaming [microsoft-excel](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) to [excel](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel), because "excel" is not ambiguous.

Even though "Microsoft Excel" is the full name of the software, "Excel" is the name commonly used. A prefix should only be added if the this name is ambiguous.

Comment: Should this also go for exchange and onenote?

Comment: @Tom: I guess, please leave a note for those you find, thanks :-)